# Unique random number generation with database table

Tags: java, oracle

We have a process of generating 10 million random numbers in each week and store them in database table (Oracle).
We have below logic to create random numbers with given range. And we are maintaining strict uniqueness of generated number with previously generated numbers 
(which already in db table). We have achieved this by indexing table column which stores random number and catching exception when inserting to table 
(Regenerate random number in case of exception). It takes almost 1 day to complete this process and continue to rise the required time to process.

Please help us on below queries to improve the performance of this process.

1. Any possible way to improve our algorithm of random number generation?
2. Any possibility to improve database operation

Things we tried:
We have already purge table data as much as can. 
Batch insert (2500 records) to table has increased the process to 3-4 days since each exception has caused to recreate each batch of numbers again.
And we are evaluating parallel processing to get some improvement.

```
int itemsInPack = 10000000;
int pinLength = 10;
int randomSeedByteCount = 10;
long lowerRangeValue = (long) Math.pow(10.0, (double) (pinLength - 1));
long higherRangeValue = 10 * lowerRangeValue;
long numberRange = higherRangeValue - lowerRangeValue;

SecureRandom secureRandomNumberGen = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 / 8];
secureRandomNumberGen.nextBytes(bytes);
byte[] seed = secureRandomNumberGen.generateSeed(randomSeedByteCount);
secureRandomNumberGen.setSeed(seed);

for(int k=0;k<itemsInPack;k++){
    double nextDouble = secureRandomNumberGen.nextDouble(); 
    long fraction = (long)(numberRange * nextDouble);
    long pinNumber = (long)(fraction + lowerRangeValue);//Insert this to table
    System.out.println("pinNumber: " + pinNumber);
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a stored procedure in Oracle to do this? That seems like the most approriate approach?

Comment: Also what is the use-case for there random numbers?

Comment: In the database, generate a list of numbers from min to max value - sort them randomly and then get the first n rows.

Comment: These random number are for customer pins. They can use these pin and get some service from us. And customer should not be able to guess the pins.

Comment: Do you really have 10,000,000 customers each needing a pin, every week?

Comment: I would just generate a random number when the customer actually needs it, e.g. 38 digits long, store that in a table with a unique constraint. If the random number is long enough, the chances that any customer will get a unique constraint violated error is so low you can ignore it. You might purge the table of expired pins every week in periods of low activity.

Comment: Yes, we need that much of pins. we have 30, 50, 100, 200 value cards to include these pins, which customer can scratch and reload these values to their mobile and this is a actual business.

Comment: The following article describes a method to generate a massive secure unique ID in a tiny amount of constant time. The storage is very small. The query is also a tiny constant time. If you still seek for an optimized solution, you should have a look: https://patents.google.com/patent/US8423770B2/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it all in the database using Oracle's [`DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( low, high )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998095) function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE randomValues (
  rnd NUMBER(11,0) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

**Insert**:

```
DECLARE
  batchSize NUMBER(4,0) := 2500;
  numRows   NUMBER(8,0) := 1000000;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. numRows LOOP
    INSERT INTO randomValues
    SELECT rnd
    FROM   (
      SELECT DISTINCT
             FLOOR(
               DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
                 POWER( 10, 10 ),
                 POWER( 10, 11 )
               )
             ) AS rnd
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= batchSize * 1.1
    ) r
    WHERE ROWNUM <= batchSize
    AND   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                       FROM   randomValues e
                       WHERE  e.rnd = r.rnd );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This is inserting 1,000,000 rows in between 100 - 140 seconds.

You can remove the loops and simplify the code to:

```
INSERT INTO randomValues
SELECT rnd
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         FLOOR(
           DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
             POWER( 10, 10 ),
             POWER( 10, 11 )
           )
         ) AS rnd
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= :numRows * 1.1
) r
WHERE ROWNUM <= :numRows
AND   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                   FROM   randomValues e
                   WHERE  e.rnd = r.rnd );
```

However, the small number of tests I've done, this was taking approx. 200 seconds to insert 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. We will try these and let you know the outcome (Sorry for the delay in response as we are affected with flood right now and still limited access to internet)

Comment: We have managed to bring processing time to approximately 4 hours by doing below changes.
Generate random numbers by ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(lowerRangeValue, higherRangeValue) and introducing parallel processing.
(Sorry we haven't try proposed DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( low, high ) )